# c# Argument is 'ref' while parameter is declared as 'value'

Tags: c#, resharper, ref, performance

```
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(RequestContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return this.process.BeginInvoke(**ref context**, callback, state);
}

public virtual RequestContext EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    RequestContext context = null;
    this.process.EndInvoke(**ref context**, result);
    return context;
}
```

The two methods above are causing some warnings in my project.  I'm not sure I understand them. The warning is:

> Argument is 'ref' while parameter is declared as 'value'

and the location of the warning is the first parameter (context) in the Invoke calls.  Does anyone see anything wrong with this or have some advice about the issue?

Those double asterisks are the cause of the warnings. I hit "bold" on the editor and it did that so I just went with it. The asterisks are not in my code.

Comment: it's not really a big deal, I can still compile and it doesn't seem to be a problem but I really hate 'unknowns' :)

Comment: What's the type of `process`?

Comment: process is: delegate void Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.Process(ref RequestContext context)

Comment: @J Benjamin: Hmm. That sounds like a thoroughly ugly delegate signature...

Comment: well, fortunately I can't claim this as my own authoring. :)  Confusing is correct though...I'm always telling the team here, "program for your fellow programmer" ... doesn't always happen

Comment: @J Benjamin: Are you saying that your team owns `Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.Process`? That seems very odd, unless you're working for Microsoft...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ref` with delegates is a bad idea, IMO. (I'd say it's normally a bad idea anyway, to be honest. Make your methods do one thing and have one result.)

I didn't think it would work at all - but apparently it does, so long as you supply the `ref` parameter when you call `EndInvoke` as well:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    delegate void Foo(ref int x, string y);

    static void SampleFoo(ref int x, string y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming: {0}", x); // 10
        x = y.Length;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int input = 10;
        Foo f = SampleFoo;
        IAsyncResult result = f.BeginInvoke(ref input, "Hello", null, null);
        f.EndInvoke(ref x, result);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", x); // 5
    }
}
```

The behaviour here is potentially confusing... I would avoid it if at all possible.

Most uses of `ref` are due to not understanding [how parameter passing works in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)... is it possible that that's the case here? Do you really need the first parameter to be `ref`? Can you just make the *return value* of the delegate the new context instead?

Answer (score 5):

`BeginInvoke` probably isn't expecting a `ref` parameter there.  Your'e saying `ref context`, i.e. pass a reference to that object (a reference in itself).  Can you confirm the method signature for `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: The signature for BeginInvoke is identical to the method signature he's sitting in: BeginInvoke(RequestContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)..

Comment: @JBenjamin exactly, you can only use `ref` if the method signature has `ref`

Comment: Yes that's my point - `ref` does something very specific and unless the method you call also declares `ref` then you shouldn't use it.  If that doesn't make sense, suggest checking out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.71).aspx these docs

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't completely understand how `ref` works.

First of all, `ref` (or `out`) is part of the method signature, so if in the method the parameter is designated as `ref` parameter then you **must** use `ref` otherwise you **must not** use `ref`

Secondly in:

```
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(RequestContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return this.process.BeginInvoke(ref context, callback, state);
}
```

The `ref` doesn't do anything because you don't use the new value of `context` anywhere.  `ref` is like an `out` parameter except that it is both "in" and "out".  Normal parameters can be thought of as "in" only (I'm making up the term "in").

Comment: There *isn't* a new value for `context` after just calling `BeginInvoke`. That comes when you call `EndInvoke`. See my answer for an example. It's this sort of weirdness which makes it a bad idea to use `ref` for asynchronous delegates...

Comment: @Jon I realize that, I think perhaps I didn't word it clearly.  What I meant was that if `BeginInvoke` were defined to take a `ref` parameter then it would be expected that the `ref` parameter is modified, otherwise there would be no need to make it `ref`.

Comment: Yes, and the ref parameter *will* potentially be modified - and the new value read out during `EndInvoke` using another `ref` argument, as per the OP's `EndProcessRequest` method. So it being `ref` *does* do something - it allows the new value to be fetched in the `EndInvoke` call.